# Send data from WP7 phone to a near by phone via bluetooth or other mechanism

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'd interested in sending data from one WP7 to another WP7 phone so I could create 2 player games. If I understand correctly most WP7 will support bluetooth, but its not in the minimum spec, is this correct? What API's can I use to access the bluetooth, any good examples of this out there?

Comment: Seems blue tooth is not really an option. Are there any other feasible options for two player games between phones?

Comment: I could be wrong but no I don't think so. WP7 does not support any kind of peer to peer networking.  You would need a 3rd party service for two devices to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Microsoft don't provide any access to the bluetooth stack via any documented APIs in this version of the Dev tools.

They don't seem to have any sense of urgency about fixing this (or any of the many other missing features), so I wouldn't expect the situation to change any time soon.

Comment: @1adam12 I see many apps in Bazaar has Bluetooth function, why can they do that ?